# How can I retrieve tasks from task scheduler in windows server and schedule them on a different computer?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell

I want to move all my tasks to a different windows server. I have scheduled more than 100 tasks that run at a specific time and on specific days of the week.
I am looking for a way where I can just retrieve all the tasks in a script and execute that script on the new server.

```
# Create an array of scheduled tasks
$tasks = @(
    @{
        Name = "Task1"
        Description = "Description of Task1"
        FilePath = "C:\Path\to\Script1.ps1"
        TriggerType = "Daily"
        TriggerDaysOfWeek = @("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday")
        TriggerStartTime = "08:00"
    },
    @{
        Name = "Task2"
        Description = "Description of Task2"
        FilePath = "C:\Path\to\Script2.ps1"
        TriggerType = "Weekly"
        TriggerDaysOfWeek = @("Saturday")
        TriggerStartTime = "10:00"
    },
    # Add more tasks as needed
)

# Loop through the tasks and register them on the target computer
foreach ($task in $tasks) {
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $task.FilePath
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At $task.TriggerStartTime
    if ($task.TriggerType -eq "Weekly") {
        $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek $task.TriggerDaysOfWeek -At $task.TriggerStartTime
    }

    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $task.Name -Description $task.Description -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -CimSession $targetComputer -Force
}
```

This was one way which I thought might work. But I am looking for different ways where I can generate the details of the task automatically. So that I can schedule all the tasks without any errors. If there is a way to do this with a powershell script, bash script.

Comment: Have you tried to manipulate XML by using [Export-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/export-scheduledtask?view=windowsserver2022-ps) and [Register-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask?view=windowsserver2022-ps) ?

Comment: Using these commands, I will have to provide all the inputs manually in the export scheduled task method. I am trying to generate this xml automatically as per the tasks already scheduled with their paths. @Daemon-5

Comment: Export to XML is the way to go, you can use [schtasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks) as well, it can make it a bit easier. You will need to add some manipulations to make it fully export and import as it doesn't "just work". This post looks like can guide you to a solution - https://www.windowscentral.com/how-export-and-import-scheduled-tasks-windows-10